# Using calculus of variations to deduce lower bound on Pitman efficiency (asymptotic relative efficiency) between $t$-test and sign test

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, efficiency, variational

Let $Y_1,...,Y_n$ be iid draws from a location family $\{f(\cdot - \theta) : \theta \in \mathbb{R}\}$. $f$ is a symmetric density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with finite variance. We want to test $H_0 : \theta = 0$ versus $H_1 : \theta > 0$.

Let $S_n$ denote the sign-test statistic which is given by
$$S_n
= \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n I_{Y_i > 0}
$$
and $T_n$ denote the $t$-test statistic which is given by
$$T_n 
= \bar{Y}/S
$$
where $S$ here is the sample standard deviation.

It can be deduced that the Pitman efficiency is
$$\mathfrak{p}(\phi_{\cdot,S_n},\phi_{\cdot, T_n})(f)
= 4f^2(0) \int y^2 f(y) \,dy.
$$
We want to show that
$$\inf_f \mathfrak{p}(\phi_{\cdot,S_n},\phi_{\cdot, T_n})(f)
\geq \frac13.
$$
**My question:** A priori, we can test various densities here and see that the uniform density gives us an efficiency of 1/3. From this knowledge, we can begin to deduce why $f$ must be uniform in order to show what the lower bound of the Pitman efficiency here is. I would like a different approach. Assume that we did not know a priori that the lower bound is 1/3. Suppose we simply want to minimize the integral
$$\int y^2 f(y) \,dy.
$$
**How can we do this using variational calculus?** Some constraints to keep in mind are that $0 \leq f \leq 1$, and that $f$ is symmetric. Further, since $f$ is a density, $\int f = 1$. I would like an approach which deduces that $f$ is the uniform density without knowing that the lower bound is 1/3 to begin with. Can we use some Euler-Lagrange equation here?

Edit: See comments for discussion on some assumptions.

Comment: By "symmetric" do you mean that $f(y)=f(-y)?$

Comment: The problem with this minimization problem is that there is no $f'(y),$ either in the original integral or the constraint. That makes using the Euler Lagrange equations challenging, if not meaningless. Intuitively, I would not expect a uniform distribution to be the best. Indeed, a uniform distribution wouldn't even make sense unless you have compact support, right? Wouldn't a Gaussian give you a smaller value?

Comment: Something else is really weird, here. Is there a constraint on $f(0)?$ I could dream up a distribution where $f(0)=0,$ which zeros out your Pitman efficiency and violates the lower bound.

Comment: Great questions. Assume f(0) = 1. Symmetric here means symmetric about the y-axis such that $\int_0^\infty f = 1/2$.

I agree with you that I don't really see why a uniform would be better than a distribution with very light tails. I see why a Cauchy would be terrible, but what's the reason a uniform gives a better bound than the normal? It seems as though there should be a more "deductive" way to get to $f$ being uniform rather than just checking various distributions.

Comment: The Euler-Lagrange equations lead to nonsense in this case. You have to use a Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ to minimize $$\int\left[y^2 f(y)+\lambda f(y)\right]dy,$$ but the E-L equations lead in this case to $y^2+\lambda=0,$ which is impossible to satisfy. I don't think the variational approach will help in this situation, unfortunately.